Colly not detecting more than one sub-element from an element
I'm scraping images from a website using Colly, I've managed to get the relevant HTML Code that contains the URLs of the images that I need, however, when I try to append them to an array using Colly, it only manages to get the 1st image.
Here's my code
    c.OnHTML("div.container-chapter-reader", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.ChildAttr("img", "src"))
    })


Here's the complete HTML that I've managed to get when I run fmt.Println(e.DOM.Html())
<div style="text-align: center; max-width: 620px; max-height: 310px; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
    <div style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; float: left; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="bg_162325351"></div>
        <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="//platform.bidgear.com/ads.php?domainid=1623&amp;sizeid=2&amp;zoneid=5351"></script>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 310px; float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
        <div>
            <script data-ssr="1" data-cfasync="false" async="" type="text/javascript" src="//ja.embolipokies.com/t666c45463f0d1/42238"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/1-1718890564-n.webp" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 1 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 1 - MangaNato.com" /><img
src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/2-1718890568-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 2 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 2 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/3-1718890568-o.jpg"
alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 3 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 3 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/4-1718890569-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 4 - MangaNato.com"
title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 4 - MangaNato.com" />
<div style="text-align: center; max-width: 620px; max-height: 310px; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
    <div style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; float: left; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="bg_162322284"></div>
        <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="//platform.bidgear.com/ads.php?domainid=1623&amp;sizeid=2&amp;zoneid=2284"></script>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 310px; float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
        <div id="pf-6966-1">
            <script>
                window.pubfuturetag = window.pubfuturetag || [];window.pubfuturetag.push({unit: "658261d2a4aa62003d239fd7", id: "pf-6966-1"})
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/5-1718890570-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 5 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 5 - MangaNato.com" /><img
src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/6-1718890570-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 6 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 6 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/7-1718890573-o.jpg"
alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 7 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 7 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/8-1718890574-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 8 - MangaNato.com"
title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 8 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/9-1718890574-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 9 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 9 - MangaNato.com"
/><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/10-1718890575-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 10 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 10 - MangaNato.com" /><img
src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/11-1718890576-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 11 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 11 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/12-1718890579-o.jpg"
alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 12 - MangaNato.com" title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 12 - MangaNato.com" /><img src="https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/13-1718890579-o.jpg" alt="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 13 - MangaNato.com"
title="One Piece Chapter 1118: Being Free page 13 - MangaNato.com" />
<nil>

However, my code only returns
https://v12.mkklcdnv6tempv4.com/img/tab_32/00/00/52/aa951409/chapter_1118_being_free/1-1718890564-n.webp

